# Vue filter table items

Tags: vue.js

There is such an example in bootstrap-vue: [complete-example](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#complete-example)

But when I choose to filter by name nothing happens.

And I am trying to repeat this example on my vue project. Nothing happens too.

[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ufm24?fontsize=14)

And my items have a status options ("success, "warning", "danger").

I have corresponding buttons.

**Question:** How to filter items by clicking on the corresponding buttons? And how to filter items by clicking on the checkbox?

[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ufm24?fontsize=14)

P.S: bootstrap-vue 2.0.1, bootstrap 4.3.1, vue 2.6.10

Comment: You need to supply the table with something to filter on via the `filter` prop. That's why nothing is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following codepen. Just add one more checkbox for the Status column.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-owbfo